# Combobox is not beeing displayed in Chrome in XPages

Tags: xpages

I have a combobox and It works great in IE. But I would like it to be worked on google chrome. I think It's about some css settings but I could not find which CSS property I need to work with. I tried **"-webkit-appearance:none 
 (/checkbox/listbox/etc...)"** css property but It does not work. Please find the picture of How it looks like in Google Chrome.

```
<xp:comboBox id="ResPerson" value="#{document1.ResPerson}" valueChangeListener="#{changeRequestBean.valueChangeListener}">
<xp:selectItems id="selectItems1">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:try {
 var rList = ["A","B", "C"];
        return rList;
    } 
    catch(e) 
    {
        print(e.toString();
    }}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:selectItems>
</xp:comboBox>
```

[image: Combobox Code]Hi,

Comment: Which version of Domino server are you running and which version of Chrome is it not working on? I don't know of a specific issue, but I would not be surprised at issues with older versions of Domino and a current version of a browser. Typically versions of the two pieces of software is the starting point if something doesn't work on a specific browser.

Comment: Domino: 9.0.1 FP6
Chrome : Latest version (59.0.3071.115 (64 bit)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, when hitting such issues, bear in mind XPages is built on Dojo. Search for issues with Chrome, the relevant component and Dojo. It sounds like this Chrome issue could be the cause https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome-admins/lOa89-9DF30. Downgrading Chrome to v54 should solve the problem, if this is indeed the cause. I've not heard of anyone else reporting the issue though, so I would recommend confirming it's an incompatibility introduced into Chrome by downgrading Chrome.

I've not gone past the first link on Google, but further searching on "Chrome combobox Dojo" will identify if Google have identified the cause or got a fix.